# Which view subclass do I use to get the threads and forum with pagination but still have reverse matching?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

models.py

```
class Forum(models.Model):
  ...

class Thread(models.Model):
  ...
  forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum, related_name="threads")
```

I want to have a page containing the threads for a specific forum:

I tried

views.py

```
class ForumView(ListView):
  template_name = ...
  model = Thread
```

But I'm not sure how to access that specific forum that has all those threads--especially if I wanted to add a new thread--I need to access the forum's pk so I can use it for a reverse match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override get_queryset() on the ListView to filter the list, eg.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^forum/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ForumView.as_view(), name='forum') 

# views.py
class ForumView(ListView):
    template_name = ...
    model = Thread

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(forum=self.kwargs['pk'])
        # you could do the same thing using the related name but you
        # would then need to fetch the Forum instance first, eg:
        # forum = models.Forum.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        # return forum.threads.all()
```

Comment: How does the self.kwargs['pk'] work? Would it show the forum's pk or the thread's pk?

Comment: --is pk supposed to be inherent? because I'm getting an error: KeyError at /forum/forum/1/

'pk'

Comment: That is why I included the snippet of the URLs.py, to show where, in the regular expression, I am capturing some digits from the URL and assigning them to 'pk'.  If, in the regex, I were to use 'forum_id' instead of 'pk', then the value passed in the URL would be available in the view as self.kwargs['forum_id']

Comment: If you are getting a KeyError when you try to access something in a dict (kwargs is a dict object) then that means the thing you were trying to access was not there.  Check your urls.py to make sure the URL pattern in question is matching the digits and assigning them to a variable name  matching the variable name you are trying to get from kwargs.

Comment: Ah, I never really understood how the regex expressions fit into the views.py thank you that solved my problem well. Is there a resource you know of to look more into those regular expressions for the urls.py?

Comment: They are pythons standard regex, doc here describes assigning names to matched groups... https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups

Comment: Thank you for the resource I'll look into it, I was also wondering where the value comes from as in what variable? It's sent from the previous page but I can't find any indicator that shows that the views or urls is getting it from some where.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.. The user clicked on a link for a particular forum to get to this view didn't they?  So the link href contained the pk of the forum.. It has to.  And how did that get there on the previous page?  Well.. it was put there by the template and view that generated the previous page that had your list of forums on it.

Comment: OK thanks...that makes sense. It was extremely helpful